# Random 500 & 404 errors - Gitlab

Tags: out-of-memory, http-status-code-404, gitlab

I get random friendly 500 and 404 errors on my Gitlab installation. Everything works fine except that.

It is really annoying, sometimes the pages work, sometimes I need to refresh the page a couple of times for it to display.

Here's the errors I get in `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`

```
ActionView::Template::Error (cannot map `/home/git/gitlabhq/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/charlock_holmes-0.6.8/ext/charlock_holmes/dst/share/misc/magic.mgc' (Cannot allocate memory)):
1: - file = tree_full_path(content)
2: %tr{ class: "tree-item #{tree_hex_class(content)}", url: tree_file_project_ref_path(@project, @ref, file) }    3:   %td.tree-item-file-name
4:     = tree_icon(content)
5:     = link_to truncate(content.name, length: 40), tree_file_project_ref_path(@project, @ref || @commit.id, file), remote: :true
6:   %td.tree_time_ago.cgray
7:     - if index == 1
app/helpers/tree_helper.rb:4:in `tree_icon'
app/views/refs/_tree_item.html.haml:4:in `_app_views_refs__tree_item_html_haml__359204534986361082_50783740'
app/views/refs/_tree.html.haml:37:in `block in _app_views_refs__tree_html_haml__2791169573873392874_51939480'
app/views/refs/_tree.html.haml:36:in `each'
app/views/refs/_tree.html.haml:36:in `_app_views_refs__tree_html_haml__2791169573873392874_51939480'
app/views/refs/tree.html.haml:2:in `_app_views_refs_tree_html_haml__1175555315298044292_52501320'
app/controllers/refs_controller.rb:40:in `tree'


^GOut of memory (Needed 8160 bytes)

ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: MySQL client ran out of memory: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` ):    25:       %h5 Users
26:       .data.padded    27:         = link_to admin_users_path do
28:           %h1= User.count
29:         %hr
30:         = link_to 'New User', new_admin_user_path, class: "btn small"
31:  config/initializers/connection_fix.rb:22:in `execute'
 app/views/admin/dashboard/index.html.haml:28:in `block in _app_views_admin_dashboard_index_html_haml___3571568531981020694_30874020'
 app/views/admin/dashboard/index.html.haml:27:in `_app_views_admin_dashboard_index_html_haml___3571568531981020694_30874020'
```

I am new to the Ruby world.

Additional Notes:

- OS: Centos 5
- Gitlab v2.8.2
- The issue almost never appears on admin pages or what not.. only on repository pages such as file tree, graphs or commits

Comment: What version of GitLab are you using. Have you already many git repo? That might be better answered in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues

Comment: Version 2.8.2. I have only 2 repos and 4 users.

Comment: Does the issue persists with a downgraded GitLab ? (2.7), or with no repo and no users?

Comment: I really don't have time to try to downgrade Gitlab. The issue almost never appears on admin pages or what not.. only on repository pages such as file tree, graphs or commits.

Comment: Ok, so maybe opening an issue on GitLab would be the best course of action here.

Comment: Okay I'll do that. Thanks for your input

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with it, but i also get "--broken encoding: unknown" instead of some commits messages